# Image height getting compressed on Android

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I am trying to create a facebook-like feed on my app.

For the image on every post, I am trying to scale it to occupy the full width of the post like this -

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="12dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have used the `RelativeLayout` as a wrapper so as to make it work on different devices properly.

However, I encounter a strange problem on some phones (Nexus S and Nexus One as per the Android Studio emulator's test screens, and on the Samsung Galaxy Duos phone) -

The image scales to occupy the full width of the parent but does not scale in height so as to maintain the aspect ratio.

I have tried changing the height of the `ImageView` in the java code but even that doesn't seem to work. The image still appears as if someone hammered it from the top to shorten its height.

I would like to know if there is a solution which I can use to solve this problem across all android screens.

Comment: Have you tried ImageView height as 'match_parent'?

Comment: `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` or `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` so the height will not change .
Either you should define the `width` and `height` static .Set display width as height from code.